# Module Federation with multiple react versions and css isolation

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, webpack-module-federation

I have a module federation remote repository that is:

1. built using react 17
2. material-ui 4 including jss
3. has its own global css from 3rd party libraries that I cannot edit

I have multiple hosts that are:

1. built using different versions of react 16 with no scope for upgrade anytime soon
2. uses material ui 3 including jss
3. have their own global css from other 3rd party libraries

Is there a way to design my remote in a way that it can work in different environments like this?

I have tried a bunch of examples from here but none of them are a complete solution:

https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples

Comment: found a solution. ended up creating an adapter wrapping all the federated components before exposing them from the remote. the adapter basically does the following:
1. creates a div as a shadow container

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Ended up creating an adapter wrapping all the federated components before exposing them from the remote. The adapter basically does the following:

1. creates a div as a shadow container and attaches to the parent component.
2. calls react.dom render / hydrate on that div based on mount vs update using the remote react version (do not declare react as a singleton in this case) Note: only works if there is only one react 16 in the project and others are react 17+
3. injects all the css inside the shadow dom
4. sets the ref for mui styles on the shadow dom -> you need to clear the mui styles cache if the provider for this is going to be unmounted and remounted
5. All popover components need to be passed a ref to the parent component so that the don't attach to the document root

Fonts are an issue since they don't work if only declared in the shadow dom. There's a chromium bug for it. So they need to be loaded in the light down as well.